# I have seen the movie

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following two sentences.

> I have seen the movie and she has too.
>
> I have seen the movie and she also has.

I think the first one sounds idiomatic but is the second one wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, and the meaning is the same. The second is a bit more formal, the first is more common in casual speech.

Comment: in both cases a comma before "and"  would be possible.